# Is it necessary to create seperate .xml files rather than using DisplayMetrics?

Tags: android, xml

I am preparing a chess game and I *have* to declare many ImageViews Buttons dynamically.
However, my friends said that it will not support other screen sizes, but I heard about DisplayMetrics code; we can get the screen width and height through code only.

Well I am using different drawables for different screen sizes. Can I release my application in google playstore like this?

Comment: Use the Genymotion emulator and check how it looks in different screen sizes. Or use the preview mode on Android Studio and check there (where you see multiple different device layouts at once)

Comment: actually my emulator is not working in my android studio. I debug all my code in my mobile only. So is this GenyMotion emulator something else or integrated with android studio only?

Comment: its right whatever you said but don't you think that it increases the complexity of app, it will be far better if you use xmls.

Comment: "i HAVE to declare many ImageViews Buttons dynamically" -- no, you *chose* to do this. Other programmers would take other approaches (animating existing `ImageView` widgets, rendering the whole thing using a `Canvas`, rendering the whole thing in OpenGL, etc.).

Comment: I think xml would make your app more complex as there will be about 100 views on 1 layout, wich is not recommended.

Comment: if you have different drawables, I don't see any good reason not to use the built in system and put them in the different drawables- folders.

Comment: that's the thing i am worried, there may be about 64 imageViews that may be needed, and
@CommonsWare- The procedure you are saying is way too larger than xml dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it however you feel better, but using xml files would result in **less code** to write, to maintain and to execute at runtime.

So, i'd go the standard way (xml files).

You can still use the programmatic way, but then you have to mess with getWidth, getHeight and multiply by the density scale factor, ... you have to do some math!!

Comment: I also want to do it that way bro, but i had to define many imageviews dynamically. I just wanted to release for every screen size possible. So is it possible without using different .xml s?

Comment: as i am getting screen width and height easily, and i am generating my imageViews according to that ratio. I am just asking is it acceptable by google?

Comment: Yes, why not? Unless you don't write a game emulator (automatic espulsion from the Play Store!!), a virus or something malicius, you can do what you want freely.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done without XML, but i would use a canvas for chess.

Maybe something like this:

```
private Paint createChessrBoard(int size)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size* 2, size* 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint fill = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    fill.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    fill.setColor(0x22000000);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, size, size);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, fill);
    rect.offset(size, size);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, fill);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bitmap, BitmapShader.TileMode.REPEAT, BitmapShader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    return paint;
}
```

You can use this to get the devices DPI

```
int dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```